# How to pass more than one variable from Python script to c shell script

Tags: python, c, bash, shell, subprocess

I do know how we pass one variable from python to c shell script but I am having trouble in passing multiple python variable to c shell script. Please let me know how do we achieve this. Here is the link where I came to know to pass single variable from python to c shell script.

[How to pass the Python variable to c shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366418/how-to-pass-the-python-variable-to-c-shell-script/26367435#26367435)

Comment: The answer you're using as a starting point is... really quite awful; `shlex.split()` rather explicitly **shouldn't** be used in this case.

Comment: That said -- what have you tried so far, and how did it fail?

Comment: None of this is specific to csh, by the way -- the environment and argument vector are both universal concepts; passing content through them is the same no matter what language the receiving program is written in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass each argument as a separate argv entry:

```
first_var='hello'
second_var='world'
subprocess.Popen(['program_name', first_var, second_var], shell=False)
```

By contrast, if you want to pass multiple variables *through the environment*, they should both be keys in the `env` dictionary:

```
subprocess.Popen(['program_name'], env={
  'first_var': first_var,
  'second_var': second_var,
})
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, This is exactly what I was looking for as the previous solution that I referred in the question was bit confusing.