# How can I launch a cshell terminal from a python script that will launch shell?

Tags: python-3.x, shell, environment-variables, launch, pyvenv

I wanted to write a custom python script that will launcg a cshell when i run the python script. Also while launching, it automatically invokes a venv and env variables while launching.So it will be a custom shell for some custom scripts.

Comment: You can take a look at [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), to execute c shell. At [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366418/how-to-pass-the-python-variable-to-c-shell-script) SO post, they ask how to pass a variable from python to a cshell, so it also shows how to run it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Note that stackoverflow is not the place to ask for free consulting services. It's a place to ask for help after you have made an effort to solve the problem yourself.